# LG Ultrafine crashing MacBook - Panic Report - UPSB: thunderbolt power on failed

Tags: display, usb, sleep-wake, crash, kernel-panic

MacBook powered from the monitor.

Locking screen.

No waking up, computer restarted due to crash.

It's happening over and over again.

```
Anonymous UUID:       9678FF68-9D96-49C0-35C6-02F05323418E

Tue Dec 12 14:52:21 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f9589c71b): "UPSB: thunderbolt power on failed 0xffffffff\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IOPCIFamily/IOPCIFamily-320.1.1/IOPCIBridge.cpp:1297
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8202ce3a90 : 0xffffff801506b6f6 
0xffffff8202ce3ae0 : 0xffffff8015196f54 
0xffffff8202ce3b20 : 0xffffff8015188c39 
0xffffff8202ce3ba0 : 0xffffff801501d190 
0xffffff8202ce3bc0 : 0xffffff801506b1cc 
0xffffff8202ce3cf0 : 0xffffff801506af4c 
0xffffff8202ce3d50 : 0xffffff7f9589c71b 
0xffffff8202ce3db0 : 0xffffff7f9589d25a 
0xffffff8202ce3dd0 : 0xffffff7f9589b5bf 
0xffffff8202ce3e20 : 0xffffff7f958a5d0f 
0xffffff8202ce3e40 : 0xffffff8015689215 
0xffffff8202ce3eb0 : 0xffffff8015688fba 
0xffffff8202ce3ed0 : 0xffffff80150a4ce4 
0xffffff8202ce3f40 : 0xffffff80150a47e5 
0xffffff8202ce3fa0 : 0xffffff801501a4f7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1A5661CA-0F8F-3EC1-B3B4-5A9ADDAE360F]@0xffffff7f95894000->0xffffff7f958c8fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
17B1003

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.2.0: Fri Sep 29 18:27:05 PDT 2017; root:xnu-4570.20.62~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B214D53-883B-3E5F-A115-9FDA17E68BA8
Kernel slide:     0x0000000014e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8015000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8014f00000
System model name: MacBookPro13,3 (Mac-A5C67F76ED83108C)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2210032244809
last loaded kext at 2207415367225: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9acde000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 608714479492: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7f9911e000, size 40960)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.1.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.1.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.1.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.1.14
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   23.0.15
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4736
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.24
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   280.12
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.16.19
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.16.19
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.16.19
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics  10.2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.1f1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4100   1.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   2.0.1
com.apple.kext.AMD9510Controller    1.5.8
com.apple.AVEBridge 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.16.19
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.21.6
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.1.3
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 127
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1200.26.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.IOBufferCopyEngineTest    1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  203
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 280.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    600.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  6.0.1f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.1f1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   517.17
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.16.19
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 280.12
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.16.19
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.16.19
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    374.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    517.17
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   209
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  310.35
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    1004.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   203
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 127
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.1f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.1f1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1004.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1000
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    52
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  52
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBufferCopyEngineFamily    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.20.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCRTC    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro13,3, BootROM MBP133.0233.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.38f7
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 530, Intel HD Graphics 530, Built-In
Graphics: Radeon Pro 450, AMD Radeon Pro 450, PCIe, 2 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x15A), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.2.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.0f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Thunderbolt@70,0,0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
USB Device: iBridge
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB3.1 Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: LG UltraFine Display Camera
USB Device: USB2.1 Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB Controls
USB Device: USB Audio
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.2
Thunderbolt Device: UltraFine 5K, LG Electronics, 1, 9.4
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.2
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it is rather late for a reply, but I had the same problem at 4:02 AM this morning. The day after I returned the Choetech Thunderbolt Power cable that I bought for $63 on Amazon and went back to the original Apple supplied cable (which seems a little looser in the LG).

The problem started happening a couple of months ago (I bought the same Macbook 13,3 with the LG in December 2016. Had the LG replaced because of screen issues a short time later.)

The restart only occurs early in the morning, but I frequently (5 times a week?) have to jiggle the cable to get the display to come on, which is one of the reasons I bought a replacement.

I have pretty much the same dump as you show.

Flummoxed!

Comment: Are you saying - one cable caused your panics and then replacing the cable, that resolved it?

Comment: I'm not sure. Problem did not happen with the Choetech in use for a week, and happened the day after I went back to the original cable. Too soon to make a judgement.